# Where was Jefferson Institute footage filmed?

Tags: film-location, coma

Where were Jefferson Institute in the movie *Coma* from 1978  filmed in Massachusetts?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

> This building was used for the exteriors of the evil medical facility (Jefferson Institute) for the 1978 movie Coma is actually the **former Xerox sales office in Lexington, Massachusetts**.
>     <sub>[Reference](http://wikimapia.org/4079611/Movie-location-Coma-Jefferson-Institute)</sub>